# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'comments')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following is my Dishdetail component in reactjs. It receives props from its parent component and and has a child component named "RenderComments" which renders the comments from the props.

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";



    function RenderDish({dish}) {
        if (dish != null) {
            return (
                <Card>
                    <CardImg width="100%" object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}></CardImg>
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            )
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div></div>
            )
        }
    }

    function RenderComments({comments}) {
        let c = [];
        if (comments != null) {
            c = comments.map((element) => {
                return (
                    <li key={element.id}>
                        <p>{element.comment}</p>
                        <p>-- {element.author}, {new Date(element.date).toLocaleDateString("en-us", { year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "2-digit" })}</p>
                    </li>

                )
            });
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h4>Comments</h4>
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    {c}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    const Dishdetail =(props)=>{
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                        <RenderDish dish={props.dish}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                        <RenderComments comments={props.dish.comments}/>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }


export default Dishdetail;
```

I get this error:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'comments')"

Since I am a beginner I do not know how to fix this error. Can please someone guide me? Also I would be glad if someone could specify the reason for this error

Comment: So comments is `undefined` and you are looking for `null`. So  you need to figure out why`props.dish.comments` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

please use optional chaining and inspect why comment comes undefined.

```
comments?.map(() => {
})
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Could you please explain it?

Comment: if an object or array has undefined or null field then you can't implement map and the other methods thus you may want to use optional chaining if you do,  to implement optional chaning you have to add "?" sign end of object or array that is in chaining.